# Using MATLAB to perform upsampling of signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I was searching for code that upsample a signal by 3 and I found thefollowing steps

```
dataSize = size(datain,2);
upsamp = [datain.' zeros(dataSize,1) zeros(dataSize,1)];
len = size(upsamp,1) * size(upsamp,2);
upsamp = reshape(upsamp.',1,len);
```

Iam not sure how these steps supposed to execute it? I am lookin  for intuition  only

Comment: If it is by a factor, simply use upsample, if not consider using resample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling):

> Interpolation by an integer factor, L, can be explained as a 2-step process, with an equivalent implementation that is more efficient:
>
> 1. Create a sequence, x_L[n], comprising the original samples, x[n], separated by L-1 zeros.
> 2. Smooth out the discontinuities with a lowpass filter, which replaces the zeros.

You can also read more details [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/csc320/notes/slidesSampling.pdf) and [here](http://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/interpolation).

Function [upsample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/upsample.html) executes only the first step, while function [resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) executes both of them. Take a look at the following code and notice the differences in the two figures:

```
close all; clear all; clc;

t = [0:0.03:1];
x = sin(4*pi*t);

% function resample performs interpolation
y = resample(x, 3, 1);
ty = [0:0.01:1.01];

figure;stem(ty, y, 'r*');
hold on;stem(t, x);
```

[image: Result using function resample]

```
% function upsample adds zeros
z = upsample(x,3);
tz = [0:0.01:1.01];

figure;stem(tz, z, 'r*');
hold on;stem(t, x);
```

[image: Result using function upsample]

Comment: Nice answer! Why don't you include the two figures, each below its code? I think the answer would be even clearer that way

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Luis! I hope it's clearer now.